# Cache SecretKeySpec due to slowness

Tags: java, encryption

```
            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(UTF_8), 65546, 256);
            SecretKey secret = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
```

One of the slowest parts in encryption / decryption is the above code. Genereration of the SecretKey takes about 95% of the decryption time. I am wondering if I can store the SecretKey in a cache like Guava to optimize.

Any thoughts on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slowness of the PBKDF2-function is a quality feature. As stated by @Henry a slow running function makes it harder for an attacker to find the correct password with a brute force attack.

The speed is affected by the number of iterations ("loops") that were run internally to get an output value - in your example "65546" is the number of iterations. Choosing a higher number slows down the calculation, a smaller number makes it faster. It's up to you to find a value that is ok for users on slow devices to calculate the password hash.

So as an answer to your question: **please do not try to shorten or caching the data to make it faster - that would reduce the security**.

Below you can find a small test routines that shows the context between number of iterations and the time in milliseconds. Beware that there is no "warmup" running so the first result seems to be too high. As well there are some "runaways" that are caused by device internal routines...

Here are the results and below the sourcecode:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749930/cache-secretkeyspec-due-to-slowness/62750840#62750840
Nr iterations  Milliseconds
   10000              374
   20000              206
   30000              262
   40000              285
   50000              337
   60000             1144
   70000              417
   80000              463
   90000              555
   100000             566
   110000             601
   120000             586
   130000             632
   140000             671
```

code:

```
   import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
   import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
   import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
   import java.security.SecureRandom;
   import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
   
   public class TimeMeasure {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
           System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749930/cache-secretkeyspec-due-to-slowness/62750840#62750840");
           char[] passwordChar = "secretPassword".toCharArray();
   
           // variables for pbkdf2
           int PBKDF2_ITERATIONS; // number of iterations
           final int SALT_SIZE_BYTE = 128 / 8; // size of salt
           final int HASH_SIZE_BIT = 256; // output size
           byte[] passwordHashByte; // output array
   
           // random salt salt
           SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
           byte passwordSaltByte[] = new byte[SALT_SIZE_BYTE];
           secureRandom.nextBytes(passwordSaltByte);
   
           // time measurement
           long startMilli = 0;
           long finishMilli = 0;
           long pbkdf2Milli = 0;
   
           System.out.println("Nr iterations  Milliseconds");
           for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
               PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = i * 10000;
               secureRandom.nextBytes(passwordSaltByte);
               startMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
               PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passwordChar, passwordSaltByte, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_SIZE_BIT);
               SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
               passwordHashByte = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
               finishMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
               pbkdf2Milli = finishMilli - startMilli;
               System.out.format("   %-15d%7d%n", PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, pbkdf2Milli);
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is slow on purpose to make dictionary attacks harder. If you use the same salt each time, an attacker could do the same and precompute keys.

Comment: The question is if the slowness is really required in this context.

Comment: @Codo yes, but we don't know the context.

Comment: I am not worried about the slowness. If I remove that, am wondering if its okay to cache